# PDE fouriertransform

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Im supposed to find the solution of ODE (10) with $\lim_{y \to \infty} u(x,y) = 0$. I have done the same as the soultionsheet and got the general solution (11). But the next step confuses me, howcome we knpw thath the D(w) = 0 when we use the foruiertransform? Can somebody please explain the theory behind the calculation?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: You are Fourier transforming in $x$ only. So $\lim_{y \to \infty} u(x, y) = \lim_{y \to \infty} \hat{u}(w, y)$. And you require $\lim_{y \to \infty} u(x, y) = 0$ which, by the above, implies $\lim_{y \to \infty} \hat{u}(w, y) = 0$. Note that the term in $\hat{u}$ with coefficient $D(w)$ is unbounded as $y \to \infty$. Therefore, to satisfy the limit condition you need $D(w) = 0$.